# hover zoom on image in a table

Tags: html, css

I have made a table that does not have any space between it as I want it as a map that will get larger when you hover over it. I have used zoom div from W3 schools but it does not work in my table. I think it is something with the size of the table but I don´t really know here is the code

```css
#casti_male {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/*ZOOM MAPY*/
.zoom {

    transition: transform .08s;
    width: 214px;
    height: 115px;
  }
  
  .zoom:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(1.5); 
  }
```

```html
<div id="mapa">
        <table id="casti_male" style="width:1495px; height: 804px;" cellspacing="0px;" cellpadding="0px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="zoom"><img src="castimapy-male/obrazky0.png"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="zoom"><img src="castimapy-male/obrazky1.png"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="zoom"><img src="castimapy-male/obrazky2.png"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="zoom"><img src="castimapy-male/obrazky3.png"></div>
                </td>
                
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

It is bigger but here is the short version. Basically on hover it is supposed to get larger while not moving anything else AND still being packed together like - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivXav.png)

Comment: should be `class="zoom"`

Comment: oh my god I am so stupid. Thank you!

Comment: Besides changing ID to CLASS, another observation is you have an extra end </td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Class instead of Id in Div and it should work like a charm. Check the following code--